# Getting [error] Mouse: not useable (blocked) while using Sikuli in Mac

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sikuli-x

I have used Sikulix maven dependency and getting below error while executing the script:
**[error] Mouse: not useable (blocked)**
Please find code snippet below

```
Pattern p = new Pattern("path of the image");
org.sikuli.script.Screen s = new org.sikuli.script.Screen();
s.hover(p);
s.click(p);
```

Could someone please help to resolve above isssue

Comment: were you able to solve this?